# Opening Cytoscape session freezes while finalizing

Tags: cytoscape

When I try to open a session it gets to the read session and freezes it won't load. The program runs, but attempting to open any sessions freezes at finalization.
[Screenshot of Cytoscape session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH720.png)

I restarted my laptop multiple times and tried reinstalling the program, but that didn't work. I then updated the program from 3.9 to 3.10 but it did not solve the issue either. I am on the latest version of Windows 11. I sent the file to my desktop and the file opened just fine.

Comment: What version of Java do you have?

Comment: Hi @ScooterMorris I have Java 17.0.5

Comment: Do the sample sessions load, or do you get the same issues?